# ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen cause delay for on-screen keyboard on UWP

Tags: uwp, fullscreen, on-screen-keyboard

I am developing a UWP app and I have an issue with the On-Screen keyboard when I set the app in FullScreen mode. 
The problem is super easy to reproduce. You just need to place any text input control in your document, then set the app in FullScreen mode. 
When you try to use the On-Screen keyboard, the characters don't appear right away and sometimes don't appear at all, unless I tap on the edit field multiple times. 
It looks like there is an issue with the focus of any text input when in full-screen mode, but I have no idea what to do about it.

Any suggestion on how to deal with it?

Below some simple reproduction steps:

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <RichEditBox Width="500" Height="200"/>
</Grid>
```

CS

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
}
```

Thanks so much!!

Claudia

Comment: I can't recreate, make sure it applies on multiple machines and OS versions

Comment: It happens on two different devices for me. DELL XPS15 9560 and Surface Pro 3 but I just realized it only happens when running in Debug mode from Visual Studio. The Released installed version doesn't have problems, which is fine. You can consider this issue close for me.